# spring how to logout on no db connection

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, iframe, exception

I have a home page like which has an iframe like

```
<iframe id="contentframe" name="contentframe" src="Report.html"
        style="height: 99%; width: 100%;" frameborder="0" >
</iframe>
```

and i have a exception handler like

```
@ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
public ModelAndView handleAllException(Exception ex) {

    ModelAndView mv=new ModelAndView("Login");
    mv.addObject("loginForm", new LoginForm());
    mv.addObject("loginMsg", "No Database Connection");
    return mv;

}
```

but when db connection lost while processing request for `Report.html` the `Login.jsp` loads within the iframe .i want it load outside the iframe as whole page.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You will need to find a way to detect the iframe changes. This is an html/javascript issue.

Comment: what is the code in test()

Comment: @Sotirios Delimanolis only when a exception occur i what the reponse come out of iframe

Comment: You have to handle it within test method in javascript. `onload="test()"` Try to find iframe location.href and if it is login.jsp try to redirect whole page to login.jsp again using location.href

Comment: @stya  test() has js code for formating the content text,i thing that wont affect anything

Comment: @Subin is there no other way in spring to achieve this

Comment: @user2779544 spring is helpless here. Spring dont know if you are loading the exception view in IFrame or not. You have to use javascript to redirect.